# Casting a Dictionary<int, List<User>>

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, casting, ienumerable

What is the most efficient way to cast a `Dictionary<int, List<User>>` to a `Dictionary<int, IEnumerable<User>>`?

The reason for this is that I have a method which builds a `Dictionary<int, List<User>>` but I would prefer not to return a mutable `List` to the calling code.

Would I have to project this dictionary into the new type?

Comment: Does the dictionary need to hold a `List<User>` as value at all? You could fill a `List<User>` and add it to a `Dictionary<int, IEnumerable<User>>`.

Comment: If you can you could write a method that returns an IEnumerable which does the index look up for the caller. That way you won't have to convert it all in one go, but only per index request.

Comment: Making it `IEnumerable` does not prevent mutability. You want an either an immutable collection or to "freeze" the collections if you want to guarantee that the underlying lists can't be changed by the caller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can return an `IEnumerable` but under the hood it'll be a `List`. A developer may well cast it to a `List` and add or remove items

I think you're looking for **[Immutable Collections](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2013/09/25/immutable-collections-ready-for-prime-time.aspx)**

Briefly, it's a nuget package that enable us to use/create truly immutable collections; meaning that any collections changes are not reflected back to what exposed them.

**EDIT: Cast to IEnumerable does not grant immutability**

Given *Guilherme Oliveira* answer one can do the following and add a new user to the users

```
    var userDictionary = new Dictionary<int, List<User>>();
    userDictionary.Add(1, new List<User>
    {
        new User{ Name= "Joseph"},
    });
    IDictionary<int, IEnumerable<User>> newDictionary = userDictionary.ToDictionary(p => p.Key, p => p.Value.AsEnumerable());
    ((List<User>) newDictionary.Values.First()).Add(new User {Name = "Maria"});
    Console.WriteLine(newDictionary.Values.First().Count()); //now we have two users
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do just like this:

```
var userDictionary = new Dictionary<int, List<User>>();
IDictionary<int, IEnumerable<User>> newDictionary = userDictionary.ToDictionary(p => p.Key, p => p.Value.AsEnumerable());
```

Comment: What are the performance repercussions here for a very large dictionary?

Comment: @davenewza: the best if for you to benchmark it; How large is your dictionary?

Comment: @LuisFilipe: There could be hundreds of keys and each could be associated to a list of hundreds of Users.

Comment: `p.Value.AsEnumerable()` will involve no cost as it returns a reference to the original list. Copying a dictionary for hundreds of keys will not take too much time at all. I just copied a dictionary with 1000000 entries in 0.05 seconds.

Comment: Please read my updated answer: returning an IEnumerable does not grant immutability which, from your question, seems to be what you're looking for

Answer (score 1):

You would need to project this to a new dictionary, e.g.

```
Dictionary<int, List<User>> myDictionary = ...;
Dictionary<int, IEnumerable<User>> resultingDictionary = myDictionary.ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => (IEnumerable<User>)kvp.Value)
```

You are unable to perform a cast from `Dictionary<int, List<User>>` to `Dictionary<int, IEnumerable<User>>` because if you could, the following would be possible:

```
Dictionary<int, List<User>> myDictionary = ...;
// Still a reference to the original dictionary
Dictionary<int, IEnumerable<User>> castDictionary = myDictionary;

// If the line above was possible, what would this do? (A HashSet<T> is not a List<T>)
castDictionary.Add(5, new HashSet<User>());
```

You may also want to take a look at covariance and contravariance on interfaces to see where the limitations lie.

Comment: Actually, when you set `myDictionary` to `castDictionary`, you're not casting it. If you want to change the value to another type, you have to cast using `AsEnumerable()`

Comment: Read the line above that example and the comment below that assignment, I said if it was possible, which it isn't.